# Permissions issue when using PHP system and cURL?

Tags: php, linux, shell, file-upload, curl

I'm trying to create a php script that will put a file on a remote server. 
The following line will work from the CLI:

```
curl -u username:pass -T myfile.jpg sftp://my.domain.com/dir/
```

However, if I take this into PHP and try to run it through 'system' like:

```
<? system('curl -u username:pass -T myfile.jpg sftp://my.domain.com/dir/'); ?>
```

I get an error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xx.xx: Permission denied
```

Also, to complicate things, this is going from a RHEL to a Windows Server. Anyone have a suggestion or a fix?

Below is the result from the PHP cURL library.

```
* About to connect() to my.domain.com port 22 (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xx.xx... * connected
* Connected to my.domain.com (xxx.xxx.xx.xx) port 22 (#0)
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password
* Initialized password authentication
* Authentication complete
* Upload failed: Permission denied (3/-31)
* Connection #0 to host my.domain.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: it might be possible that your still ssh using the user that run the php script and that the username and password you use are just for authentication, which "apache" (assuming its running php) user is not authenticated to upload files to that remote folder

Comment: I thought this might be the problem, but I'm not sure how to remedy this issue. Even if I give full-control to "Everyone" on the Windows server (terrible solution, I know), it still fails. If I run the script in the command line "php myscript.php", my script works fine. But, running it from a web browser, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has it's own cURL library that you should probably use. [php cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: I actually tried using the cURL library, but without success. My guess is that it's the same permissions issue.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you might have to install the cURL extension yourself. http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php If your server has a package manager, you might be able to get it from there and have it be installed and configured automatically.

Comment: Good thinking, but cURL is enabled. I have updated my question with the CURLOPT_VERBOSE results.

Comment: As someone commented on your question, your problem might be that the user that is running PHP, which is probably whatever user your webserver runs as, doesn't have the right permissions. Either with your local system, or your remote system. I would check into setting permission for the php user to use the curl command.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `system()` doesn't allow `curl` to ask you for a password.

Consider other authentication methods.